# My iis automatically points my solution directory though it's published

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, deployment, publish

I have published my `IIS` application to `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/appDirectory` and it's have different configuration in `web.config` file.
and in development version solution directory i have another `web.config` file and When i build solution my `IIS` start pointing to solution directory.

that's too annoying, every time i need to remove application from iis and again make application on `IIS` itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to properties of your web service in Visual Studio.
2. Navigate to Web tab
3. Either Change the local IIS to express or you can give a different application name so it wont replace your deployed application.

[image]